# By using android gradle,how to pack a file to apk zip root directory?

Tags: java, android, ant

1. By using ant build system, I can put sample.xml file under $projectDir/src directory, and when ant build finished, the file is in the generated apk's root directory.
2. But this method does not work in gradle build system. How can I get the same result by using Android Studio(gradle)? Thanks.

Comment: This is probably bad practice, since support files should go into "assets" subfolder. Though a lot of projects contain something in the apk root, and with Android Studio it's (correct me if i'm wrong) impossible to compile and/or run them.

Comment: Yeah,I find this can't be done from android gradle plugin.And I use zip and resign apk to solve it.